# Change the <p> content when img area is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I need to know how to change the text inside of `<p>` tag when img area is clicked. The text that should be set to the `<p>` tag is inside the area alt code. Can i extract the alt text and set it to `<p>` tag?

Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/DjNzg6Y9

Thanks :)

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). **1.** Your code should be included in the question, not just an external link. **2.** Your code should be concise and trimmed to include only what's relevant to your question. **3.** You must first make a reasonable attempt to solve this issue on your own. If your attempts fail, include details of your them, making sure to tell us what about them is not working.

Comment: I am learning html at the moment so i dont think you need to be rude. I just want a solution i looked online and I couldnt't find anything that I could work with

Comment: meta charset inside the <head> tag?? That is something to start with ;)

Comment: @ I did not know What you are looking for is Javascript, not html. I think it is a little bit too early to start with that if you don't know html.

Comment: Thats how we learned in school so idk then what should i do

Comment: if you go on my profile on stack exchange you can see what im working on. I got a working javascript code that changes some text on websites so that people with dyslexia can read it easier. What im stuck on is the Settings site for Chrome extension so yeah.. :/

Comment: @Ididnotknow Then include the working javascript code in your question and clarify why it isn't working for you. You can't expect us to write your code from scratch. If you don't know how to even *start* writing the code, then the simple answer is to either: **A)** Learn the basics of javascript from the multitude of free, online resources or **B)** Hire someone.

Comment: @Santi I didnt ask you to write the code from scrathc for me what i asked for was a way to do it even if you would post a link i would be happy with the answer because there would be something that i could work on. I said i have a working javascript code what im stuck on is the settings page for html where i need to set text in p tag when img area is clicked.. so sorry if i offended you in any way if i wanted help online and not waste anymore time that i already did(1-2 hours) trying with tdifferent things and nothing worked.. Sorry again

Comment: where I can get this image : Slike/keyboard_layout.jpg?

Comment: @MaxZoom http://imgur.com/a/vgBel here is the link to the picture

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working example:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<p>Old Text</p>
<img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="Content of alt">

<script>
    (function () {
        // definitions
        var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
        var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];

        // listeners
        img.addEventListener("click", function () {
           p.innerHTML = img.alt;
        });
    })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and `jsfiddle`

> https://jsfiddle.net/Lak2d6zw/1/

Comment: Thank for you effort :) I'm gonna tag this as the answer :)

Comment: Remember that I used getElementsByTagName but in your case there can be better other functions, for example getting by class, id, or more flexible like querySelector.

Comment: Kinda figured that one by myself but thank you again you dont know how much you helped me with this :D

Answer (score 0):

Check this one:

```js
var $img = document.getElementById("yourID").getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
console.log($img.alt);
```

```html
<a id="yourID">
    <img alt="hello world" src="http://www.hbhud.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/EA-Logo-2011-150x150.png">
</a>
```

It should works fine

Cheers